# Bash: pass arguments from file line-by-line

Tags: file, bash, arguments

I am reading arguments from a file, line-by-line, but each line has several arguments. The gist of the code is below

```
cat file.txt | while read LINE ; do
    echo -e `./foo.sh "$COUNT" "$LINE"`
done
```

foo.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$2\t$3\t$4"
```

file.txt

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

returned. Note it is not tabbed

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 0 1
```

This is simpler example of what I'm trying to do; my foo.sh is actually making a sql call using the arguments. I know that my foo.sh function works through debugging, so I've narrowed it down to the line reader. Any help with where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do either:

1. Unquote the variable
2. Eval the string

So it becomes either:

```
echo -e `./foo.sh "$COUNT" $LINE`
```

or

```
echo -e `eval ./foo.sh "$COUNT" "$LINE"`
```

Otherwise bash will call `foo.sh` passing `$LINE` as a single parameter. By evaluating it explicitly, bash will first generate the final command string, and then reinterpret it, actually splitting `$LINE` into separate arguments.

Hope this helps =)

Comment: Perfect. I tried both seperatly and both solutions make it function correctly. Any preference for which solution is better?

Comment: Either solution works? Cool! I thought that they had to be together. I guess the back-quote behaves similarly to eval. I would prefer to use the option without eval then =)

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho: Re: "I guess the back-quote behaves similarly to eval": Net exactly. What happens is, when you don't quote a parameter-substitution, it undergoes word-splitting and filename-expansion. That's not just inside back-quotes; it also happens in a regular command. (See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting.) `eval` does much more than that, in that it also processes internal quotes like `"` and `'`, redirection operators like `<` and `>>`, and so on.

Comment: @ruakh: Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho - also, eval is evil...  Look up what `set --` does instead.  Rather than an eval, one could `set -- $LINE` to set she script's positional parameters to the whitespace-delimited words in the variable, then perhaps `while [[ -n "$1" ]]; do something; shift; done`  If one is using bash, one should use bashisms!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you're nesting the outer command in an echo?  What about something like this?  I just added -e to the echo in foo.sh and took out the echo in the outer call.

```
cat foo.txt | while read LINE ; do
    ./foo.sh $COUNT $LINE
done
```

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "$2\t$3\t$4"
```

Comment: No need cat. `while read LINE ; do; ./foo.sh "$COUNT" $LINE; done < foo.txt`

Comment: outer command is actually being used to append to a file, so it looks closer to this:

    cat file.txt | while read LINE ; do
        echo -e `./foo.sh "$COUNT" "$LINE"` >> tmp
    done

It may not be necessary for that either, I'm still learning all this